# Proof of Borel-Cantelli

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am trying to understand the following implication in the proof of Borel-Cantelli. To set it up for you, we are given:

Let $A_i$ be a seq. of events and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\sup A_n = \bigcap_{n\geq1}\left(\bigcup_{m\geq n} A_n \right)$. The statement is, if $\sum_{n\geq 1}P(A_n) < \infty $ then $P(\limsup A_n)=0$.

My question is, why does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1_{A_n}} < \infty \;P-a.s.$ imply that $P(\limsup (A_n)) = 0$?

And if I have explicitly $A_n$ given as the open interval $(0, \frac{1}{n})$ with sample space $\Omega=(0,1)$, sigma algebra $=\sigma((0,1))$ and the Lebesguemeasure on $\Omega$, why it then $lim sup(A_n)=0$?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but you are equating $$\sum_{n\geq 1}P(A_n) < \infty $$ with $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1_{A_n}} < \infty \;P-a.s.$$ although the former obviously implies the latter, but not the other way round.

Comment: It is used in the proof. Using the monotone convergence theorem it goes like this: $E\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty1_{A_n} \right) = \sum P(A_n) < \infty$, where $E() = Expectation$ then we use the above to conclude, but I don't understand the implication

Comment: Yes, as I said, the sum of probabilities being finite implies that the sum of functions is finite almost surely, **but not the other way around**.

Comment: Thank you, but how exactly does the former imply the latter? Thanks

Comment: I mean is it really not the other way around, since $0 \leq P(A_n) \leq 1$ and $1_{A_n} = 1$

Comment: Hmmm... do you know what the notation $$1_A$$ even mean?

Comment: Let $w \in \Omega$. Then $1_A(w) = 1$ if $w \in A$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately, in this context, your previous comments become rather difficult to understand...

Comment: which one in particular?

Comment: When you state that $1_A=1$, for example. Say, where are you leading this?

Comment: well forget that. i am trying to understand your first statement. why exactly does the former imply the latter and not the other way around?

Comment: Because if the expectation of a nonnegative random variable is finite then the random variable is almost surely finite, but not the other way around. (But of course if you do not see that asserting that $1_A=1$ is a huge problem, there is little chance you can understand the matter, sorry to say.)

Comment: why should 1 not be equal to $1_A$? I mean both have a one in it

Comment: Yeah, that you do not get the difference is kind of the problem... Anyway: $$\text{Number}\ne\text{Function}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint for your second question, expand: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\sup A_n = \bigcap_{n\geq1}\left(\bigcup_{m\geq n} A_n \right)=(A_1\bigcup A_2\bigcup A_3\bigcup ...\bigcup A_n...)\bigcap\bigcap(A_2\bigcup A_3\bigcup ...\bigcup A_n...)\bigcap(A_3\bigcup A_4\bigcup A_5\bigcup ...\bigcup A_n...)\bigcap...\bigcap(A_n\bigcup A_{n+1}\bigcup A_{n+2}\bigcup ...)\bigcap...$$

Now, if $A_n=(0,\frac{1}{n})$ try to see which element(s) will be in ALL intersecting gaps $(\cdot)$

Comment: Ah, i see. {0} will be the element left. Thank you.